# how to catch error, when I'm trying to parse impossible date in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

There is some kind of user input in spreadsheet. When someone input date like "30. 2.", error is occured. I understand why, but how to catch this error?

```
 var mDay = "30";
var mMonth = "02";
var mYear = "2023"; 
mStart = "00:00";
var mDate = mDay + mMonth + mYear + mStart;
  try {
    mDate = Utilities.parseDate(mDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "ddMMyyyyhh:mm");
  }
  catch (err) {
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('')
      .setWidth(350)
      .setHeight(30);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, "Invalid date!");
    return;
  }
```

I'm expecting, that instead of system error I'll recieve my own message.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the alert dialog

```
function test() {
  try {
    var mDay = "30.";
    var mMonth = "02.";
    var mYear = "2023"; 
    var mStart = "00:00";
    var mDate = mDay + mMonth + mYear + mStart;
    try {
      mDate = Utilities.parseDate(mDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "ddMMyyyyhh:mm");
      console.log(mDate);
    }
    catch (err) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Invalid date!")
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, why not, But I still recieve red box "Exception: Parametry (String,String,String) neodpovídají podpisu metody pro Utilities.formatDate." instead of my own alert.

Comment: I ran this from a menu option and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I add "console.log(mDate)" and it works.